# ClickOnce Deploy to Secure Web

Tags: visual-studio, iis, sharepoint, clickonce

For the last year we've been working from home, and using VPN to connect to the office network for program updates.

Lately we've decided to try to find away to remove the need for that connection, and I would like to remove the need for any kind of file share, as replacing the VPN with a different VPN seems silly.

I know that VS can make a deployment web page and upload it to FTP, which solves half the problem, but I also don't want just anyone who finds the webpage being able to download and install the app.

We have a web server running IIS, and we also have a sharepoint site on office.com

If I install it to IIS, is there a way to secure it to our employees with azure active directory?
Is there a way to put it on the sharepoint site, which is already secured?

I just haven't found good resources to solve either problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the question of `is there a way to secure it to our employees with azure active directory`.

If you want to do it in IIS level, I don't think it can be implemented. But we can do it in application level. You can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory) about how to develop your application with Azure AD.

Comment: That's neat! I have set up an intranet style page that might work for right now, but this looks like a good set of extra protection to put in place.